# Open a module located in a different folder

Tags: alloy

My problem is quite trivial but I can't find a solution to it.

I'm trying to open a module using a command of the form : `open ../folder/module`, but this leads to a syntax error.
How to correct that ?

ps : the 2 modules have to be in a separate folder, and those folder's have to be "siblings folders" (one can't be contained in the other)

Thanks and Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of those slides helped me solve this proiblem.

http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~tinelli/181/Notes/05-alloy-modules.pdf

cheers

Comment: So how did you solve your problem without changing your file/folder structure?  I don't think you can't use ".." in the path specifier, so I really don't know how to open a module located in a parent (or sibling) folder.

Comment: You need to name your module starting from the root of your folder structure.

naming my module folder1/module rather than module then allows me to open for example folder2/module where folder 1 and folder 2 are siblings folder.